# Нужно чтобы бот телеграм ( pyTelegramBotAPI) сохранял фото, которое отправил пользователь боту, на указанную директорию. Python

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Сохраняет только файлы, а при отправке фото выдёт:'NoneType' object has no attribute 'file_id'

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['document'])
def handle_docs_photo(message):
    try:
        chat_id = message.chat.id

        file_info = bot.get_file(message.document.file_id)
        downloaded_file = bot.download_file(file_info.file_path)

        src = 'C:/Users/Dima/Desktop/' + message.document.file_name;
        with open(src, 'wb') as new_file:
            new_file.write(downloaded_file)

        bot.reply_to(message, "Пожалуй, я сохраню это")
    except Exception as e:
        bot.reply_to(message, e)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.